# Checking license for external sites - web service

Tags: php

I'm wondering if anyone can offer any advice on the following situation.

I'm developing a system, which will then be installed on peoples own servers. However, i want people to pay a subscription fee for using this system. If they do not pay I want to be able to disable the system externally.

Basically when the system is run it does a call in the background to my server, which checks the license key, if it exists and is active they can use the system as normal.

I've got a basic function that calls my external site (sort of a web service) which checks the key exists. However, anyone with a bit of knowledge could just alter the function so it returns true and bypass the external check.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this, even if it makes it slightly more harder for them to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode your code, e.g. with ionCube. However, the customer then needs to set up ionCube on their own server to be able to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually put the main logic/controllers onto YOUR server.
So it would be more SaaS (Software as a Service).

If that's not possible, you might encrypt (some of) the code on the customers server with keys and certs, so what you sell is a private key to your customer.

Besides that, have a look at Zend Guard.